# Remove duplicate rows based on two different columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using SQL in MS-Access.
I would like to remove only the duplicate rows based on two different columns (`code` and `geode`).

my table:

```
| **code** | **fim** | **geode** |
|  AAA     |    yes  |    no     |
|  AAA     |    yes  |    yes    |
|  BBB     |    yes  |    yes    |
|  BBB     |    yes  |    yes    |
```

expected result:

```
    | **code** | **fim** | **geode** |
    |  AAA     |    yes  |    no     |
    |  AAA     |    yes  |    yes    |
    |  BBB     |    yes  |    yes    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `distinct`:

```
select distinct code, fim, geode
from t;
```

Comment: Thak you! but how do I delete these rows? Do I have to use this 'select distinct' in the where condition?

Comment: @Req_7 . . . Deleting the rows is very tricky because you have no unique column or columns to define each row.  I would suggest just repopulating the table with no duplicates.